# Restrict calendar booking to certain 'slots' in SharePoint 2010

Tags: calendar

In SharePoint 2010, is it possible to only allow people to add events to a calendar with restriction in place. e.g. only between the hours of 9am and 5pm, or only in predefined slots (which could be set in another calender). Ideally would then use colour codes so the user can see at a glance what slots they can book in.

Answer (score 1):

You'd likely need to add javascript validation to the newform to limit that or use content approval on the items.